# what is the better option for storing comments in temp table?

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008, streaming

I am making a real-time web chat plugin that uses data from a table that will only contain the data while a stream is playing. I was thinking about making an xml field to store comments.

Would this be more efficient and easier to do then creating another table to temporarily store comments?

I am using c# and sql server 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to keep your solution relational, and there are many reasons to do so, you are better off creating another table (or several) to manage the comments. This allows you to use traditional SQL queries to perform [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operations on the comments, while at the same time limiting your dependencies on SQL Server specific features.